# angular Cannot read property 'html5Mode' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, route-provider, location-provider

in my angular application i want to make redirect with $location.path('/');
but i'm getting this error 
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp.login due to:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'html5Mode' of undefined
here is my code

```
angular.module('myApp.login', ['ngRoute', 'angular-md5'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/login', {
templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
controller: 'loginCtrl'
});
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
}).hashPrefix('!');
}])
```

Answer (score 3):

You missed to add dependency in the DI array before using it in factory function of a config block.

**Code**

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', //<-- added dependency before using it in function
     function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
```

Comment: That happens.. Np.. Glad to help you..Thanks :)